# opencart product carousel issue when click on image

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, opencart2.x

[opencart product carousel and popup magnifition of product image after click on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC2Pf.jpg)

Hi dear anthers,
I have a problem in opencart product carousel that when my customers are clicking on the image of product block in product carousel it shows the image of product instead of redirecting customer to the page of product. How can I make it so that when I choose `inspect element` it shows in the code file a jquery icon at the end of code row. The jquery code box in debugger contains a magnificent popup code for showing an image. So how can I disable it so that when a customer clicks on the image of product, a product page opens after.

This is the code of product:

```
<div class="image clearfix">
     <a class="img" itemprop="url" title="Kunc euismods" href="http://localhost/pavo1/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=138">
      <img class="img-responsive" itemprop="image" src="http://localhost/pavo1/image/cache/catalog/demo/cosmetic/4c-199x201.jpg" title="Kunc euismods" alt="Kunc euismods">
      </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to change the class name "image":

```
<div class="image clearfix">
```

to something else, or change the jQuery trigger at the very bottom of the page, as this makes the links within the `<div class="image"></div>` all behave as Gallery Popups.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image').magnificPopup({
        type:'image',
        delegate: 'a',
        gallery: {
            enabled:true
        }
    });
});
```

Personally I'd go for changing the class as the Magnific popup is tied into several features throughout the Opencart system.